# como puedo "extraer" de una cadena en C usando fscanf?

Tags: c, funciones, algoritmos

Quiero usar como un filtro al fscanf() por ejemplo si hago lo siguiente teniendo un registro con dos campos, el primer campo es "ignorado" y lee el segundo campo

```
fscanf(fd, "%*d, %d", &numero)
```

Como pondría si quiero leer una parte de la cadena de un campo, me explico
teniendo una URL ej: https://www.google.com/gmail/ que solo me guarde la ultima parte del dominio del servidor o sea *com*

Puedo de alguna forma ir ignorando parte de la cadena?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

de hecho no hay forma de hacer ese *filtro* en C, todo tienes que implementarlo tu.
Si tan nesesario es el `scanf()` puedes usar la biblioteca `<string.h>` para analizar el url, yo te pongo una solucion sin usarla.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //creo un lugar para almacenar com, net, etc, nunca seran mas de 3 letras
    char array[3];
    //creo recorredores it y r, c es un entero porque convierto chars a enteros por tabla ascii
    int c = 0, it = 0, r = 0;
    while (c = getchar()) {
        //si el iterador encuentra q esta en el 2do punto, vamos a guardarlo
        if (it > 1 && r < 3) {
            array[r] = c;
            r++;
        }
        //si encuentro el punto, aumento al iterador
        if (c == '.') it++;
        //si el limite del almacenamiento llega, nos salimos del bucle
        if (r >= 3) {
            break;
        }
    }
    //para imprimir, el arreglo de chars hacemos..
    c = 0;
    while (c < 3) {
        printf("%c", array[c]);
        c++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

No me gusta usar `scanf()` para esta situacion, ya que sere muy eficiente en el analisis de la url `getchar()` es la funcion adecuada para un analisis en tiempo de ejecucion, pero tu puedes acondicionar el programa para que lo haga con `scanf()` si gustas.

La logica es sencilla, si cuentas los puntos, das con el dominio `com`, `net`, etc.

Comment: Gracias por la idea! aunque hay url que no tienen necesariamente dos puntos, me diste una idea, gracias por comentar!